# Navigation through theorems in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, navigation

I am writing a proof with a certain number of lemmas and theorems and I would like to navigate through them easily, via the Structure View.

[image: an image of the Structure View]

But, only structures (section, subsection, paragraph, ...) shows in the Structure View.

Is there a way to make all the environments created via the command newtheorem (theorems, lemmas, ...) appear in the Structure View ?